# RPC that supports commitment processed

Tags: solana-program, rpc

Does anyone know of any Solana mainnet RPC that supports get_transaction requests with commitment below confirmed? Currently, all the ones I tested only support confirmed upwards, but for my project I need to check how the transaction turned out as quickly as possible (preferably checking with commitment processed)

Answer (score 2):

The ones I know for sure that support processed are: quicknode, helius, triton.

There are more though. Check them out here: https://solana.com/de/rpc

To listen to processed account changes you can do this:

```
export const connection = new Connection("rpcUrl", {
  commitment: "processed",
})

const subscriptionId = connection.onAccountChange(
      accountAddress,
      (accountInfo) => {
        const decoded = program.coder.accounts.decode(
          "gameDataAccount",
          accountInfo.data
        )
        console.log("New account data via socket processed", decoded.playerPosition)
      }
    )
```

Here is the rpc call docs for it:
https://solana.com/de/docs/rpc/websocket/accountsubscribe

Comment: In my quicknode paid plan I can't get transaction with `processed` status.. Same thing with helius.

Comment: Maybe you need to request the blockhash with processed commitment for it to work.

Comment: If you use js also set your connection to processed by adding : commitment: 'processed'  as parameter when you create the connection

Comment: I tried setting the client connection to processed as well, but I still get the error that getTransaction can only be processed at levels starting from confirmed

Comment: Could you post the exact error please? And when and where you see it?

Comment: A few seconds after sending a transaction with sendTransaction, I try to check the transaction data with getTransaction, passing commitment="processed" as the parameter, as I would not like to wait until the transaction is confirmed to obtain the data. And I get the error below:

InvalidParamsMessage {
     message: "Method does not support commitment below `confirmed`",
}

Comment: If you are interested in the data of an account after it changed look into onAccountChange. There you get the fastest updates. Triton and Helius even give you mit block updates via dragon mouth plugin like that: // Subscribe to account changes
const id = connection.onAccountChange(<PUBKEY>, (accountInfo) => {
  // Handle account change...
});

Comment: I am interested in getting the amount I received after making a swap, but the swap transaction is not in confirmed status yet. Do you think this way should resolve the issue? Can you send the name of the RPC method?

Comment: connection.onAccountChange

Comment: Which RPC are you talking about? Could you send the link to the documentation that contains this method, please? I didn't find it here

Comment: https://solana.com/de/docs/rpc/websocket/accountsubscribe and here is an implementation of it: https://github.com/solana-developers/solana_game_preset/blob/main/app/contexts/GameStateProvider.tsx

Answer (score 2):

`getTransaction` does not support returning `processed` transactions. This is due to how transactions are inserted into the blockstore only after being replayed by the network, and not when they are processed by the leader.

You can read more about it in this GitHub issue https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/34663