# Get Accounts involved in a transaction using Rust

Tags: web3.js, rust, jsonrpc-api, solana-sdk

Suppose I have the signature of a transaction that has been **processed**, I want to get the accounts involved in a transaction. Usually I would look at the staticAccounts field of a transaction using the getTransaction() call which is only available for "confirmed" transactions. Is there a way to get the accounts involved ? This should possible to get from only the transaction signature. Perhaps a json request is needed or some rust call (from solana-sdk) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RPC that supports commitment processed](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8998/rpc-that-supports-commitment-processed)